# Sort custom text in chronological order

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns, week-number

I have created a calculated column which simply concatenates the week number along with the week start date and is of course stored as a text.

What I want to do is actually sort this text column in chronological order in order of weeks and year.

[image]

I cant sort it using any of my date columns as there will be duplicate values for every value in the `weekNumWeekCommence` column

Does anyone know a work around for this problem?

Comment: Is this a column in your calendar table?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: Create a week commencing column in your calendar (same logic as you have for you concat) and then sort by that.

Comment: thanks that worked - you could submit it as an answer so it can get marked as the solution

Comment: Glad to hear. I'll do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a week commencing column in your calendar (same logic as you have for you concat) and then sort by that.